# XHR Chunk upload has one issue while uploading a text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

Iam using a XHR chunk upload in my ColdFusion project. The upload is working fine with all type of files except the files having .txt extension.
When I'm trying to upload a text file it will be uploaded and become empty (File size become 0 bytes).

Why this is happening?

Here is the exception which I'm getting...

```
An exception occurred when executing method write.The cause of this exception was that: coldfusion.runtime.Cast$NumberConversionException: The value Hello this is a test file. cannot be converted to a number..
```

Here is my **home.cfm**

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Chunk Upload</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   .text-center{text-align: center;}
   #alert{color: red}
   #uploading, .filesize{color: red}
   #success{color: green}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

            var blobs = [];

            function bytesToSize(bytes) {
      var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
      if (bytes == 0) return '0 Byte';
      var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
      return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
   };
  /*
   * function that uploads a fragment of the file
   */
                function uploadChunk(blob, fileName, fileType, count){
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('POST', 'chunkUpload.cfm', false);
                    xhr.onload = function(e){
                    document.getElementById("success").innerHTML = "Uploading... <span class='filesize'>" + count + "</span> MB";
                    }
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X_FILE_NAME', fileName);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', fileType)
                    // document.getElementById("uploading").innerHTML += "Uploading chunk of size " + blob.size + ".<br/>";
                    xhr.send(blob);
                };
  /*
   * Invoke this function when the submit button is clicked.
   */
         function uploadSubmit(){
         var fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll('#userfile');
         for (i = 0; i < fileInputs.length; i++) {
                  sliceFilesToFragments(fileInputs[i]);
                 }
         };
  /*
   * function that slice the file into 1MB fragment
   */
         function sliceFilesToFragments(input){
              var count = 0;
              var file = input.files[0];
                    // Upload 1 mb per chunk
                    var bytes_per_chunk = 1024 * 1024;
                    var start = 0;
                    var end = bytes_per_chunk;
                    var size = file.size;
                    document.getElementById("TotalSize").innerHTML += "Total File size <span class='filesize'>"+bytesToSize(size)+"</span>";
                    while (start < size) {
           //push the fragments to an array
                        blobs.push(file.slice(start, end));
                        start = end;
                        end = start + bytes_per_chunk;
                    }
                        var blobArray = blobs.slice();
              //upload the fragment to the server
                    while (blob = blobs.shift()) {
                     count++;
                     if(blobArray.length == count){
                      count = 'File Uploaded Successfully';
                     }
            uploadChunk(blob, file.name, file.type, count);
                    }
         };

  </script>
    <h2 class="text-center">Chunk Upload using XHR & CF</h2>
  <form name="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   <pre>
    * notes *
    1) Refresh Each time, before upload
    2) Uploading 1 mb per chunk for now
    3) To see the chunks: go to Chrome > inpect element > Network tab
   </pre>
   <pre>
    Upload:<input type="file" id="userfile"><br>
   </pre>
   <pre>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="uploadSubmit()"><br>
   </pre>
   <pre><span id="TotalSize"></span></pre><br>
   <pre><span id="success"></span></pre>
  </form>
 </body>

</html>
```

Here is my **chunkUpload.cfm**

```html
 <cfoutput>
 <cfset headerData = getHTTPRequestData().headers>
 <cfset content = getHTTPRequestData().content>
 <cfset filePath = expandPath("./Uploads/") & "#headerData.X_FILE_NAME#">
 <cfset fos = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init(filePath, true)>
 <cfset fos.write(content)>
 <cfset fos.close()>
</cfoutput>
```

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? I'm getting the exact same error.

Answer (score 1):

My issue got resolved by changing the content type of the file. Update your content-type as below

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/octet-stream");
```